# How to find the minimum value of $ax+by+cz$ given $x,y,z$ are non negative integers that satisfy $x+2y+3z=d$?

Tags: number-theory, vectors, linear-programming, maxima-minima

how to find the minimum value of the given expression $ax+by+cz$ if the constraints are $x,y,z$ are non negative integers that satisfy $x+2y+3z=d$, where $a,b,c,d$ all are positive integers and known beforehand.
Or if I substitute one variable from the equation the question can be also asked as
How to find minimum non negative value of $Ax+By+C$ given that $x,y$ are non negative integers and A,B are integers?

Comment: Likely the constraint should be $x+2y+3z=d$ rather than $x+2y+3x=d$.  It would also help to put the given expression in the question itself, rather than just the title.

Comment: @Michael edited

Comment: What if you remove $x$ from the problem? Can you rewrite in a simpler form without $x$?

Comment: @Michael that would be I guess 
How to find minimum non negative value of $Ax+By+C$ given that x,y are non negative integers and A,B are integers.

Comment: I do not follow your above comment. I expected you to substitute $x=d-2y-3z$ everywhere you see an ``$x$'' in the objective function, while carefully considering how the constraint $x \geq 0$ is transformed when you remove the $x$.  You can reduce it to minimizing a function $h(y,z)$ subject to constraints on $(y, z)$.

Comment: @Michael I just replaced the variables $y,z$ in the final equation to $x,y$ for sake of simplicity.

Comment: You can replace the $z$ variable if you prefer, but not the way you tried to do it.  If you write $z = (d-x-2y)/3$ then you indeed want to minimize $ax + by + c(d-x-2y)/3$, but you need to also ensure that the original constraint $z \geq 0$ is upheld.  So that constraint also needs to be transformed.  The constraint that $z$ is an integer would also need to be enforced (and this enforcement is now more awkward since you have decided to remove the $z$ variable rather than the $x$ variable). It would also be helpful to keep notation the same and not change notation midway through.

Comment: The minimum of $Rx + Sy + T$ over all nonnegative integer pairs $(x,y)$, with no other constraints on $(x,y)$, and for given integers $R, S, T$, is trivially $-\infty$ if either $R<0$ or $S<0$ (since we can choose $(x,y)$ to make $Rx + Sy+T$ as negative as we like), or equals $T$ (achieved by $x=y=0$) if $R\geq 0$ and $S \geq 0$. But, that is not the answer you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  ax + by + cz = u \hfill \cr 
  x + 2y + 3z = d \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
represents a line in 3D.

You want to find the minimum value of $u$ for which the line contains non-negative integer points.

A vector ($\bf t$) parallel  to the line is given by the cross product of the vectors normal to the planes

$$
{\bf t} = \left( {3b - 2c,\;c - 3a,\,\,2a - b} \right)
$$

and we can write the parametric equation of the line as
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  x = d - 2{{u - ad} \over {b - 2a}} + \left( {3b - 2c} \right)s \hfill \cr 
  y = {{u - ad} \over {b - 2a}} + \left( {c - 3a} \right)s \hfill \cr 
  z = \left( {2a - b} \right)s \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
i.e.
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  s = {n \over {2a - b}}\quad \left| {\,n \in \mathbb N} \right. \hfill \cr 
  x = d + 2{{u - ad + \left( {3b - 2c} \right)n} \over {2a - b}} \hfill \cr 
  y = {{ - u + ad + \left( {c - 3a} \right)n} \over {2a - b}} \hfill \cr 
  z = n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Since $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers, and assuming $0<2a-b$
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \left( {2a - b} \right)x = \left( {2a - b} \right)d + 2\left( {u - ad} \right) + 2\left( {3b - 2c} \right)n \hfill \cr 
  \left( {2a - b} \right)y =  - \left( {u - ad} \right) + \left( {c - 3a} \right)n \hfill \cr 
  z = n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

That means that, first of all, $u$ and $n$ must satisfy the congruence
relations
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  v = u - ad \hfill \cr 
  \left( {2a - b} \right)d + 2v + 2\left( {3b - 2c} \right)n \equiv 0\quad \bmod \left( {2a - b} \right) \hfill \cr 
   - v + \left( {c - 3a} \right)n \equiv 0\quad \bmod \left( {2a - b} \right) \hfill \cr 
  z = n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
which upon some simplifications leads to
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \left( {2c - 3a} \right)n \equiv 0\quad \bmod \left( {2a - b} \right) \hfill \cr 
  v = u - ad \equiv \left( {c - 3a} \right)n \equiv 3cn\quad \bmod \left( {2a - b} \right) \hfill \cr 
  z = n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
Once the solutions to these are found, it will be the case to check them against the original equations
to properly take into account the signs, and verify that $x$ and $y$ are positive, and choose the minimum $u$ for that.

*Example*, in the case $a=b=c=d=1$, the congruences give
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
   - n \equiv 0\quad \bmod \left( 1 \right) \hfill \cr 
  v = u - 1 \equiv  - 2n \equiv 3n\quad \bmod \left( 1 \right) \hfill \cr 
  z = n \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le z = n \in Z \hfill \cr 
  u \in Z \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and substituting back
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  x = 2u + 2n - 1 \hfill \cr 
  y = 1 - u - 2n \hfill \cr 
  z = n \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x + y = u \hfill \cr 
  u \le 1 - 2n \hfill \cr 
  0 \le n \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  u_{\,\min }  = 1 \hfill \cr 
  n = 0 \hfill \cr 
  x = 1,\;y = 0,z = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

The **other approach** that you suggested is also viable
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  ax + by + cz = u \hfill \cr 
  x + 2y + 3z = d \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x = d - 2y - 3z \hfill \cr 
  \left( {2a - b} \right)y + \left( {3a - c} \right)z + \left( {ad - u} \right) = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x = d - 2y - 3z \hfill \cr 
  Ay + Bz + C = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

For the resolution of the 2D diophantine equation in the 2nd line, please refer to [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829056).
The solutions to it shall then respect the inequality in the 1st line.

From the cited post you get that your problem is, in general, related to:
  - the [Modular Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) operation;
  - the [Popoviciu's Theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204037v1);
  - the [Frobenius Coin Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) problem.
and that, for some particular values of $a,b,c,d$, although non-negative, you might even have 
no solution, for whichever value of $u$.